# CPU usage according to ps and operf

Tags: linux, ps, profiling

I've acquired some data seemingly in conflict from two sources one would assume are reliable. In all likelihood, I'm misreading one of the sources.

The server environment is: Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS, 3.13.0-53-generic

On the one hand, there's a Python script that samples CPU usage and drops it into an InfluxDB which gets rendered by Grafana. The command used boils down to something like:

```
ps -eLo pid,lwp,pcpu | grep 2924  | awk {'print $2,$3'}
...
2924  2924  0.1
2924  2926  2.4
2924  2927  2.4
2924  2930  2.4
2924  2933  2.4
2924  2935  0.0
2924  3096  0.0
2924  3099  9.0
2924  3100  5.7
```

The graphs report predictably in most circumstances, though the CPU usage is only sampled every 45 seconds.

According to this graph, the thread which calls `Foo()` when it spawns has the highest CPU usage of all of the above. In fact, TID 3099 from the above actual output is the thread in question. This high usage persists throughout the day during varying data loads, etc.

On the other hand, we have the OProfile suite. I ran `operf -gl` on this program for a few hours yesterday and received a healthy chunk of data in return. When rendered with `opreport -gc`, I get the following line:

```
46423     0.2396  FooManager.cpp:625      foobinary.V0.28       Foo()
```

This is the line where `Foo()` is unindented. My reading of this, then, goes: `Foo()` is responsible for considerably more CPU usage than its fellow threads, consistently. Yet, when profiled, a mere 0.2396% of samples captured showed the function in the call stack.

That seems impossible. Surely a thread that's got the highest relative CPU usage to its fellow workers will account for the largest percentage of profile samples?